# Is there a way to make a browse-able automount directory without mounting the subdirectories?

Tags: linux, opensolaris, autofs

Question:
Is there a way to make a browse-able automount directory without mounting the subdirectories?

Background:
I am looking at moving from statically mounted NFS shares, to dynamically mounted NFS shares.  The shares are hosted on OS X and OpenSolaris systems, the clients are running Debian and Ubuntu.

I would like the user directories in /home to be dynamically mounted so that the OpenSolaris shares can each be in its own ZFS partition for quota, compression, and duplication tweaking.  The OpenSolaris/ZFS best practices guide suggests mounting each directory individually and using an automounter.  [There is also a danger with a *lot* of mounted NFS shares running into issues.](https://serverfault.com/questions/46457/any-problems-with-many-nfs-mounts)

My users to need to regularly copy data from another user's home directory, and I think they will panic if the list of user directories is not browse-able.

[This illustrates the point, but there must be better solution by now.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Automount-6.html#ss6.1)
When I set this up, the directory that hosts the to-be-mounted directory starts empty.  It is only after attempting a function (like 'ls folder_name') on a directory I know should exist, that the remote directory is mounted.  I understand this is normal for autofs and amd.

If I make symbolic links to the directories so that I have a browse-able tree for my users, each remote share is mounted automatically when the directory that hosts the symbolic links is 'ls'ed.  This is largely a waste of mounting as most of those mounts will not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; give automount the "--ghost" flag.  Don't know offhand where that's configured in Debian-esque init files.

Aha.  Edit /etc/default/autofs to contain the line:

```
DAEMONOPTIONS=--ghost
```

I believe that's right.

Comment: Hey, you are totally right.  Thank you.
If one is running autofs5 on Debian, the option is now called Browse_Mode.  So setting:

BROWSE_MODE="yes"

Took care of it.